# mencoder Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

I've tried to install *mencoder* on Raspbian Jessie, but there seems to be no installation candidate:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install mencoder
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Package mencoder is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mencoder' has no installation candidate
```

Is there a compatible version of *mencoder* for Raspbian Jessie?

*/etc/apt/sources.list* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mencoder` is no longer supported in Raspbian Jessie, try using `avconv`. Install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```